# Parsing nested JSON throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception

I am trying to parse a nested JSON  as shown below:

```
{
    "a":{"aa":"11","bb":"232"},
    "b":{"aa":"111","bb":"224"},
    "c":{"aa":"121","bb":"232"}
}
```

I am trying to get to the nested JSON part using loops:

```java
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject infoJSON = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("resources/abc.json")));                

for(int i=0 ;i< infoJSON.size(); i++){          
    JSONObject innerJSON = (JSONObject) infoJSON.get(i);            
    System.out.println(innerJSON.keySet());
}
```

It throws me `NullPointerException`. I feel there is some issue with the iteration.

Comment: Its not about "Null Pointer Exception". My question was on why is it not parsing the nested part

Comment: Sometimes questions get closed by mistake. You're getting `null` because `size()` represents the count of objects in a JSON object which is a `Map<String, Object>` itself, so that's why `get(i)` does not make sense (`0` where only `a`, `b`, and `c` exist). This is what you need: `JSONObject infoJson = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader); for ( Entry<String, Object> e : infoJson.entrySet() ) { JSONObject innerJson = (JSONObject) e.getValue(); System.out.println(innerJson.keySet()); }`

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv: any reason you haven't posted that as an answer?

Comment: @LukeWoodward The question is closed, so no answers can be posted, but I think the OP will read the comment. This is fine. I think the question might be re-closed again because the OP made a too common mistake while getting the `JSONObject` values that are actually `Map`s if the OP is using the JSON Smart library (and I believe the OP is).

Comment: I solved it looping through the keyset `for(Object key: infoJSON.keySet()){
   JSONObject innerJSON = (JSONObject) infoJSON.get(key); )`

Answer (score -2):

Your code loops for the outer objects which will cause null pointer.
Your code should looks like:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject infoJSON = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("resources/abc.json")));                
 for(int j=0; infoJSON.size(); j++){
     for(int i=0 ;i< infoJSON.get(j).size(); i++){          
        JSONObject innerJSON = (JSONObject) infoJSON.get(j);            
        System.out.println(innerJSON.keySet());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Evidently you haven't tested this as it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Yes, @LukeWoodward, the above suggestion did not help.